# How to store text-area data in database in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a form with three fields two are of input type="text" and one is text area. I am not able to store the data of text area in database. HELP

```
<table>
  <form name="email" method="post">
    <tr>
      <td width="90">
        Email Id : <input name="Receiver1" type="text" size="70"/><br>
        Subject :<input name="Sub" type="text" size="70" /><br>

          <textarea cols="80" rows="30" >
          </textarea>

       Content:<input type="submit" name="Send" value="Send" />

  </form>
<?php
 require('connection.php');
 if(isset($_POST['Send']))
 {
   $Reciever = $_POST['Receiver1'];
   $Subject = $_POST['Sub'];
   $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['textarea']);
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO EmailData VALUES ('$Reciever','$Subject', '$text')");
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? (Not that you're actually checking). FYI, you are wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174).

Comment: Your textarea isn't named. Bingo. Can I have my cookie now?

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: <textarea cols="80" rows="30" name="NAME ME SOMETHING!!!" >

Comment: Give your text area a name and look for it in $_POST, just like any other form variable.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Comment: Next time, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and save us all the typing trouble.

Comment: the error is Undefined index: textarea

Comment: ^--« There you go, see? It works! ;-) Invaluable tool isn't it? So do `<textarea cols="80" rows="30" name="textarea">` and you'll be on your way to happiness ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a `textarea` a `name` attribute for it to be a successful form control.

You are not allowed a form around a table row element. Some browsers will move the form outside the table and leave the form controls behind. **Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/)**.

Comment: nice point abt form being in tr :) +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to name the textarea:

```
<textarea cols="80" rows="30" name="textarea">
</textarea>
```

Comment: not working and the error is Undefined index: textarea

Answer (score 1):

name your textarea :)

```
<textarea name="textarea_name" cols="80" rows="30" >
          </textarea>

  </form>
<?php
 require('connection.php');
 if(isset($_POST['Send']))
 {
   $Reciever = $_POST['Receiver1'];
   $Subject = $_POST['Sub'];

   $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['textarea_name']);
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO EmailData VALUES ('$Reciever','$Subject', '$text')");
}
```

Comment: it gives the error  Undefined index: textarea_name

Comment: it means your textarea is nt named as textarea_name :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to name your `<textarea>` just like you name your `<input>`s:

```
<textarea cols="80" rows="30" name="sometext">
</textarea>
```

You can then refer to it as `$_POST['sometext']`.

That being said, please read up on [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and how to program against it.